# Mongo query for nested object inside another nested object

Tags: java, mongodb

I have few classes Employee, Department and Subject for MongoDb database and the relations are like this

```
public class Employee {
 @Id
 private long id;
 private String name;
 @DBRef
 private Subject subject;
} 

public class subject{
 @Id 
 private long id;
 private String name;
 @DBRef
 private Department department;
}

public class Department{
 @Id     
 private long id;
 private String name;
}
```

I am able to query the Employees by using subject Id

```
db.employee.find("subject.$id":<subjectId>)
```

now I am trying to fetch the employees under a Department using departmentId but am not getting any results

```
db.employee.find("subject.department.$id":<departmentId>)
```

Please let me know any options to query the Employees using departmentId in MongoDB

Sample objects in MongoDB

```
Employee ::

{"_id": 1,"name":"student1","subject":{"$ref":"subject","$id":1}}
{"_id": 2,"name":"student2","subject":{"$ref":"subject","$id":2}}
{"_id": 3,"name":"student3","subject":{"$ref":"subject","$id":3}}

Subject ::
{"_id": 1,"name":"subject1","department":{"$ref":"department","$id":1}}
{"_id": 2,"name":"subject2","department":{"$ref":"department","$id":1}}
{"_id": 3,"name":"subject3","department":{"$ref":"department","$id":2}}

Department ::

{"_id": 1,"name":"department1"}
{"_id": 2,"name":"department2"}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you share some of the objects as they appear in MongoDB, i.e. as Json?

Comment: If you're using Mongo 3.2, then you have built-in Join operations - https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/joins-and-other-aggregation-enhancements-coming-in-mongodb-3-2-part-1-of-3-introduction

Comment: But are you sure your data model is a good fit for MongoDB? In Mongo, it is typically better to model data as denormalized documents, so that joins are not needed.